# C++ code fails with 'Segmentation fault' but I can't figure out why

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, point-clouds

I've been trying to find the problem for about a week now but without success. This code is supposed to sort out the 'hull' of a pointcloud (see code comments) which is generated by another working script. All points in the input file lay on a 3-dimensional evenly spaced grid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

/* This script is supposed to take a pointcloud and remove all points except those that lie 
 * on the hull:
 * 
 * .... ...             .... ...
 * ...........          .  ... ...
 * ............   ==>   .       ...
 * ..........           ..      .
 *  .........            ........
 * 
 * This is done by taking every point 'P' and checking in a 3x3x3 grid around it if there are other 
 * points '0'. If the amount of empty grid spaces is more or equal to one then P is on the hull.
 * 
 * not in hull:     in hull:        in hull:
 *    0 0 0           0   0                
 *    0 P 0           0 P 0             P 0
 *    0 0 0           0 0 0           0 0 0
*/

int main(){

    //Settings:
    string mainfilename = "Mandelbulb.xyz";
    string hullfilename = "Hull_" + mainfilename;
    const double radiusdivider = 10.0;

    //Variables for later use:
    double xmain, ymain, zmain;
    double xmain2, ymain2, zmain2;
    double xcheck, ycheck, zcheck;
    double div;
    const double radius = div/radiusdivider;    //'Size' of a point
    int envcount = 0;   //points in the immediate enviroment (3x3x3-grid)
    int hulllinecount = 0;


    //Open file for counting lines:
    ifstream mainfile;
    mainfile.open(mainfilename);
    int linecount = count(istreambuf_iterator<char>(mainfile),
        istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n');
    linecount--;    //first line is no coordinate
    mainfile.close();


    //Coordinate arrays:
    double maincoords[3][linecount];
    double hullcoords[3][linecount];    //Has at most 'linecount'-many coordinates


    //Load file to array:
    cout << "Loading " << mainfilename << "... ";
    mainfile.open(mainfilename);
    mainfile >> div;
    for(int i = 0; i < linecount; i++){
        mainfile >> maincoords[0][i];
        mainfile >> maincoords[1][i];
        mainfile >> maincoords[2][i];
    }
    mainfile.close();
    cout << "Done\n";


    //Cycle through every point in maincoords:
    cout << "Checking " << linecount << " points... ";
    for(int i = 0; i < linecount; i++){
        xmain = maincoords[0][i];
        ymain = maincoords[1][i];
        zmain = maincoords[2][i];
        envcount = 0;

        //Cycle through 3x3x3 grid around point
        for(int l = 0; l <= 2; l++){
        for(int m = 0; m <= 2; m++){
        for(int n = 0; n <= 2; n++){
            xcheck = xmain + div - l*div;
            ycheck = ymain + div - m*div;
            zcheck = zmain + div - n*div;

            //Check if grid-point is also in maincoord:
            for(int p = 0; p < linecount; p++){
                xmain2 = maincoords[0][p];
                ymain2 = maincoords[1][p];
                zmain2 = maincoords[2][p];

                //Condition:
                if( (abs(xcheck-xmain2) <= radius) && 
                    (abs(ycheck-ymain2) <= radius) && 
                    (abs(zcheck-zmain2) <= radius) ){
                    envcount++;
                }
            }

        }
        }
        }

        //If one or more surrounding points are empty, the main point is on the hull and saved:
        if(envcount < 27){
            hulllinecount++;
            hullcoords[0][i] = xmain;
            hullcoords[1][i] = ymain;
            hullcoords[2][i] = zmain;
        }
    }
    cout << "Done\n";

    //Writing hull to hullfile:
    cout << "Writing hull to " << hullfilename << " ... ";
    ofstream hullfile;
    hullfile.open(hullfilename);
    for(int i = 0; i < hulllinecount; i++){
        hullfile << hullcoords[0][i];
        hullfile << "   ";
        hullfile << hullcoords[1][i];
        hullfile << "   ";
        hullfile << hullcoords[2][i];
        hullfile << endl;
    }
    hullfile.close();
    cout << "Done\n";
}
```

I compile the code with `g++ -g` in the Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal. When executing `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` appears. When entering `ddd a.out` and running the code there this message appears:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555559bb in main () at hullmaker.cpp:60
```

However I don't see anything wrong around line 60.

Comment: Which line is line 60?

Comment: `double maincoords[3][linecount];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant, not a runtime value.   Use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays.  Also, even if that were valid syntax, if `linecount` is some huge number, you more than likely will be blowing out the stack memory.

Comment: Other than not checking to see if those files are opened successfully, the only issue I see with the code are those two lines mentioned that are not valid C++ syntax.  Try `std::vector<std::vector<double>> maincoords(3, std::vector<double>(linecount)); std::vector<std::vector<double>> hullcoords(3, std::vector<double>(linecount))` and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: Try using gdb to debug your programm. You can debug step by step and see exactly where the program breaks, also you can get some additional information about the break cause. It helped me a lot when I was debugging my C\C++ programmes.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that `linecount`  was not correctly initialized. If the input file is not open the variable can be initialized with 0 and as you decrement the value once maybe you are trying to create an array with negative size. Try to put a const value instead and check if the code will work properly.